# Webpack is compressing my entire project, rather than bundling the js

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack-2

Whenever I run webpack, it creates a .tgz file in the project's root directory, rather than creating a bundle.js file that I can include in html.

Here's my webpack config:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
context: __dirname,
entry: './client/index.js',
output: {
    path: path.resolve('dist'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
},
module: {
loaders: [
  { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
  { test: /\.jsx$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ }
]
}
}
```

and my project structure looks like this

```
babel.rc        
dist            
node_modules        
webpack.config.js
client  
     - index.html
     - index.js 
jslib-1.0.0.tgz     < --- this is the unwanted ouput.
package.json
```

I'm running my webpack via an npm script, there were some issues with the global installation.

:in package.json:

```
...
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"pack" : "webpack"
}
```

Would really appreciate any help or advice.

Answer (score 2):

You’re probably running `npm pack` instead of `npm run[-script] pack`. In general, scripts are run with `npm run <name>`; there are a few special scripts, like `test`, that have a corresponding `npm` command, but `npm pack` is something entirely separate.

Comment: I also had a "pack" in package.json file and `yarn pack` only emitted the compressed package file. I renamed it it `package` and now I am happy.